# Java Swing Chatbot Messenger Integration

Tags: java, swing, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I built from scratch a Chatbot in java with swing. I have my own NLP engine and home-made dialogue manager.

My question is now : how could I integrate it in a website chatting app like messenger or slack ?

Thanks

Comment: If it's Swing based, there is no longer a way to embed it in a web site. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a knowledge on general Enterprise Integration Patterns.

This can be done in several ways. First thing you have to do is understand how Skype, Messanger or whatever are exposing their API in order to allow you to integrate with your service.
Usually those products have "guide for developer".

Integrating with third party service is usually done by REST APis, webhook or AMQP protocols.
There is no one way of doing that, but there are standards way.

There is a book which I can suggest which is actually called Enterprise Integration Patterns.